# How do I make a toolbar appear before other controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am new to WPF and having problems getting my GUI to display correctly. I have a Grid that has a toolbox and a UniformGrid in it. The UniformGrid has a bunch of buttons in it and there is a text box in the toolbox. My problem is unless the application window is full screen the buttons are on top of the Grid. How do I fix this, so that the buttons are bellow the grid.

Comment: First step is paste the code! -1

Comment: What kind of Panel is holding your ToolBox and UniformGrid? Your content's layout will depend on what sort of panel you have. I always recommend going over the article [WPF Layouts - A Visual Quick Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start) if you're new to WPF's layout system

Comment: its a Grid, read the question carefully @Rachel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `StackPanel` with `Orientation = Vetrical` or a `DockPanel` `toolbox.Dock = Top`

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Toolbox>
            <TextBox></TextBox>
        </Toolbox>
        <UniformGrid>
            <Button></Button>
            <Button></Button>
        </UniformGrid>
    </StackPanel>
```